# P4python: get changelist number of latest revision of file checked in in perforce by python code

Tags: perforce, p4python

i have a file abc.txt checked in perforce.
through python (using p4 python API) i want to have changelist number of latest revision of that file.
please provide runnable code.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: `p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //<depot_path>/abc.txt` is the CLI command that would provide the required changelist. Build on this and write a script. If you face any problems, edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the changelist number in the output from the 'p4 fstat' command.

To run this using P4Python, use the code:

```
result = p4.run("fstat", "<FileName>")
print result
```

The output will look something like this:

> ```
> [  
>    {  
>       'isMapped':'',
>       'haveRev':'10',
>       'headAction':'edit',
>       'headModTime':'1465312503',
>       'clientFile':'/users/jen/dvcs/usage/home/depot_create.rb',
>       'headRev':'10',
>       'headChange':'7666',
>       'headTime':'1465312526',
>       'depotFile':'//depot/scripts/depot_create.rb',
>       'headType':'text'
>    }
> ]
> ```

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: so this would provide all information about a file, right? Is there a specific API that would provide what OP wants to do. I am just curious.